# Is there a way to lock directory (the way files are locked when in use)?

Tags: windows

I'm writing an update program (using NSIS) and I want acquire some kind of lock on a installation directory to be sure I have write access to *all* files inside that directory. Is there a way to do that? Or at least how to detect that none files in specified directory are in use?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking this at StackOverflow instead?

Comment: In use by what? Anything? Or cooperating applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do what you are trying to do is to use Transactional NTFS to perform a single massive write of multiple files to the directory. This way you will not need to use locks.